# Error Updating TexShop

Tags: errors, texshop

I am currently running TeXShop Version 2.47 on OSX 10.9.2, and whenever I click `TeXShop > Check for Updates`, I receive the message "An error occurred in retrieving update information. Please try again later."

Do I need to delete and reinstall TeXShop, or is there a better way to update?

Comment: For the update from 2.x to 3.x (the current version is 3.26; 2.47 was the last version of 2.x) you need to download a new copy, I think, from the [TeXShop web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't update 2.47 to 3.xx via the update mechanism since 3.xx requires OS X 10.7 and later.

Go to <http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html> and download from there.

Good Luck,

Herb Schulz